# Exporting PYTHONPATH to parent dir doesn't work to import files from other dir

Tags: python

I have this git team project which have several folders with subfolders with some files in it. The directory look like this.

```
/C:
../Work
..../airflow
....../dags
......../automation
.........../__init__.py
.........../email
............../__init__.py
............../email_automation.py
.........../module
............../__init__.py
............../email_automation_module.py
......../otherfolder
.........../__init__.py
.........../modulefile.py
```

There's `__init__.py` in folder `automation/`, `automation/email/`, `otherfolder/` and `automation/module/` . In `email_automation.py` I want to import `otherfolder/modulefile.py` like so. But I keep getting error `No module named automation`. So I tried to export PYTHONPATH to the parent dir which is `C:/Work/airflow/dags`. I opened terminal and export the path then tried to run the file, files can be imported. Then I closed the terminal and tried to run `email_automation.py`, I'm surprised the same error happened again. I reboot my PC, tried again just to find the same error. Is there something I'm missing? I have checked references but it seemed like I already follow the directions.

```
import otherfolder.modulefile
import automation.module.email_automation_module
```